# change info in view controller depending on button

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

In the `MenuViewController` I have 2 buttons - week and month. I also have segue to `CalendarViewController` which now contains info about the month only. How can I change the information depending on one of the buttons is pressed?
I tried to use on MenuViewController:

```
   @IBAction func buttonClick(sender: AnyObject) {

            let calendarVC = kConstantObj.SetIntialMainViewController("CalendarViewController")
            self.window?.rootViewController = calendarVC
            self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
            }

        if sender  == mounthButton {
               CalendarViewController.presentationMode(.MonthView)

        } else {

CalendarViewController.presentationMode(.WeekView)
}
}
```

and on CalendarViewController I have a function :

```
  func presentationMode() -> CalendarMode {
            return CalendarMode.MonthView
        }
```

but get an error  'use of instant member 'presentationMode' on type 'CalendarViewController' , did you mean to use a value of type 'CalendarViewController' instead?'

Comment: Share the code you tried to achieve this please

Comment: just added to the question

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to set the presentation mode to the class CalendarViewController, rather than your instantiated CalendarViewController: calendarVC

Where you have

```
CalendarViewController.presentationMode(.MonthView)
```

put this instead

```
calendarVC.presentationMode(.MonthView)
```

And do the same for the .WeekView line

Also I think it would be better to call 'makeKeyAndVisible' after setting the presentationMode

Comment: I've just tried .."use of unresolved identifier" and what should I do to the function in CalendarViewController? Now it returns CalendarMode.MonthView

Comment: You need to set the identifier for CalendarViewController in your storyboard. I'm not sure what you mean for the second part?